# panel data number of observations

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, panel-data, econometrics

As I don't have experience with panel data analysis I am asking for your opinion on a rather simple matter.

Is there a general rule of thumb concerning the "minimum" number of observations needed for (balanced) panel data analysis ? I have read that one should have a minimum 100-200 of observations.

Supose we have 17 yearly observations for 4 countries. This equals 68 observations. Is this considered to be "enough" for regression, unit root and cointegration testing ?

Comment: Why not consult one of the standard panel data model references, e.g., Pesaran's massive *Time Series and Panel Data Econometrics*? He has entire chapters devoted to these topics wrt panel data models.

Comment: @DJohnson, thanks, i was not aware of this reference. However, I do not have access to this book, unfortunately.

Comment: Of course you do. Any large university library should have it in their stacks and, if not, you can request it through some sort of interlibrary loan resource.